# Problema con devolver valor de consulta

Tags: c#

Estoy leyendo archivos, estos solo se deben de leer una vez para evitar el registro de nuevo, lo que pasa es lo siguiente, en mi siguiente función
estoy llevando como parámetros el grupo y el nombre del archivo los cuales recibo sin ningún problema, la consulta que se muestra cuenta la cantidad
que hay en la tabla, es decir si el archivo ya se leyó la consulta devolverá `1`, esto quiere decir que ya ha sido leído el valor es mayor a 0, por lo que la salida es "ya existe archivo".

El problema es que teniendo el archivo registrado sigue mandando 0, como si no hubiera registro alguno, y lo vuelve a registrar, y si dejo seguir el programa lo registra cuantas veces pueda.

Me estará faltando algo? estoy poniendo algo en el lugar equivocado? la consulta la hecho directo en el gestor de BD y funciona perfectamente...

```
 public string ArchivoExiste(string grupo, string name)
        {
            string salida = "";
            string conexionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["principal"].ConnectionString;
            string count = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM  archivos C WHERE grupo = :namegrupo AND name = :namearchivo";
            using (var conexion = new OracleConnection(conexionString))
            {
                try
                {

                    using (var adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(count, conexion))
                    {
                        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(":namegrupo", grupo);
                        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(":namearchivo", name);

                        DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
                        adapter.Fill(tabla);
                        string valor = tabla.Rows[0][0].ToString();

                        if (Int32.Parse(valor) > 0)
                        {
                            salida = "ya existe archivo";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            salida = "no existe archivo";
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    salida = ex.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (conexion.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                        conexion.Close();
                }
                return salida;
            }
        }
```

Comment: que viene en valor, siempre 0??? o vendra null? o algun otra cosa?

Comment: si,siempre viene 0, y no debería de ser asi ya que hay registros del archivo.

Answer (score 0):

podrías cambiar

```
 if (Int32.Parse(valor) > 0)
                    {
                        salida = "ya existe archivo";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        salida = "no existe archivo";
                    }
```

por

```
If (tabla.Rows.Count=0)
```

{
}

Comment: perdon me equivoque pero deberia ser If (tabla.Rows.Count=0){ tabla vacia}

Comment: he implementado tu respuesta, borre todo lo de la bd, cuando llega al if que me dijiste, devuelve 1, cuando no hay ningun registro del archivo, y por ende no registra.

tabla.Rows.Count
 en tabla me devuelve 0, y en Count 1, por eso siempre dira que existe cuando es incorrecto

Comment: puedes poner el codigo del sp para ver como se retorna?

Comment: no hay sp alguno, al inicio solo voy a la carpeta donde estan los archivos que se van a leer, y luego va a esta funcion para saber si los registrara o no.....

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con este codigo

```
using (var adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(count, conexion))
                {
                    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(":namegrupo", grupo);
                    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(":namearchivo", name);
                    conecion.open();
                    DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(tabla);
                    string valor = tabla.Rows[0][0].ToString();

                    if (Int32.Parse(valor) > 0)
                    {
                        salida = "ya existe archivo";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        salida = "no existe archivo";
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Horacio, El sitio no funciona escribiendo una respuesta atras de otra. Por favor, elimina esta respuesta y edita la respuesta que diste originalmente. Si tenes alguna duda, dejale un comentario al autor de la publicacion. Tambien, por favor, explica tu codigo. Yo por ejemplo no entiendo cual es la diferencia entre este codigo y el del usuario.